# WordPress edit post list

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming, blogs

I have WordPress kanews theme.
I want to list posts by update date. but unfortunately I couldn't. sorts by creation date. how can i solve this problem?

List post by update date

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom query and pass `orderby` the value of `modified`. THis will order them by their modified date and not published date.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby'   => 'modified'
];
    
$modPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $modPosts->have_posts() ) : while ( $modPosts->have_posts() ) : $modPosts->the_post();

// Show posts here

endwhile; endif;

// Reset the query
wp_reset_query();
```